# how to mock context datasource for jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc, mocking, junit4

I have this code to connect with a Database, which is Defined by a Strutsapplication.

```
public void initConnection()
   {
     if (this.con == null) {
       try
       {
         Context ctx = new InitialContext();
         Context envContext = (Context)ctx.lookup("java:comp/env");
         this.ds = ((DataSource)envContext.lookup("jdbc/FooBar"));
         if (this.ds != null)
         {
           this.con = this.ds.getConnection();
           if (this.con != null) {
             LOGGER.info("datasbase connection established");
           } else {
             LOGGER.error("there was an error during connectiong to the database");
           }
         }
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
         LOGGER.error(e);
       }
     }
   }
```

Right now, the Context is defined using a context.xml!

```
<Context>
    <Resource name="jdbc/FooBar" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        maxActive="20" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" username="root" password=""
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ProductiveDB?autoReconnect=true" />
</Context>
```

Is there any way to Mock this Context using Java? I am writing Unit tests, and I need to connect to a Database called `TestDB`.

EDIT:
I am Using mockito to create mock my classes. I would just like to create something similar to the XML just using Java, like for example:

```
Resource resource = new Resource();
resource.setAuth("Container");
bla bla bla
resource.setURL("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/TestDB?aztoReconnect=true");
```

and then add this to my Context with

```
new InitialContext().addToContext("jdbc/FooBar",resource);
```

***EDIT II:***
I have edited my code inside my setup function to look like this:

```
ds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
ds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/FooBar");
ds.setUsername("root");
ds.setPassword("");
Context ctx = new InitialContext();
System.out.println(ctx);
System.out.println(ctx.getEnvironment());
ctx.addToEnvironment("java:comp/env/jdbc/FooBar", ds);
```

I think, this way, I got a lot closer to my solution, but now I get the following error:

```
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.getEnvironment(Unknown Source)
at com.foo.bar.su.tests.StepDefs.prepareTests(StepDefs.java:55)
at com.foo.bar.su.tests.HomeTest.setUp(HomeTest.java:22)
```

I could figure out, that this error obviously means, that my env. can not be found. But how can I "create" it, or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid to lookup programmatically as it makes your code harder to test. It's better to use a framework to control the dependency injection. Then you can use something like DBUnit.

If it's not possible to use the dependency injection you can still turn your code more testable. For instance, you can isolate the datasource lookup as follow:

```
public abstract class MyAbstractDao {
    private DataSource ds = null;

    protected DataSource getDataSource() {
        if (ds == null) {
            Context ctx = new InitialContext();
            Context envContext = (Context)ctx.lookup("java:comp/env");
            return (DataSource)envContext.lookup("jdbc/FooBar");    
        }
        return ds;
    }

    public void setDataSource(DataSource ds) {
        this.ds = ds;
    }
}
```

EDIT: You can use apache DBCP for instance and create the datasource programmatically:

```
BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
ds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
ds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/TestDB");
ds.setUsername("root");
ds.setPassword("");
```

Now you can inject the desired datasource used in your tests

Comment: Edited my Question, to make a little bit more clear, what I want to do.

Comment: I have edited my code. Could you please check my EDIT II, in the post?

Comment: Why are you instantiating InitialContext? You don`t need to inject the datasource in the RMI registry. Just implement a getter to return the datasource. Just create the DataSource in the test and set it in the DAO.

Comment: You sir, earn a nobel Prize! 
It worked perfectly. Extended my DBConnection Class with these functions. Then put the DataSource in my SetUp. It worked fine! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I use JMockit (my favorite mocking toolkit) to do this.

```
@Mocked(stubOutClassInitialization=true) final InitialContext unused = null;
```

EDIT 1:
In another case, I have something like this:

```
new Expectations() {
    InitialContext ctx;
    {
        ...
        ctx = new InitialContext(); // expect constructor
        ctx.lookup(anyString); result = myMockThingie;
        ...
    }
}
```

In my cases I'm not interested particularly to connect to an alternate database, so it's not exactly the circumstance you want, although it seems easy enough to tailor to your needs.

EDIT 2:
Thinking about this some more, maybe you could dodge the mocking altogether here. Why not just, for the purposes of your test, create a subclass of your test subject and override that initConnection() method to use the connection you want? I use this technique often enough and maybe that's the easiest thing for you here. Note that you can create a static inner class right in your test class which subclasses the test subject, so no worries about cluttering up your production code with artifacts specifically for your tests. Hope it helps!

Comment: Edited my Question, to make a little bit more clear, what I want to do.

Comment: Offered another idea for you. Good luck!